# I am having error while i am updating post in my wordpress webiste it says "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added rewritalbe code in htaccess also installed classic editor but they dont seem to solve my problem i have checked network in developers tool and it showing following error in it

**WordPress database error:** [Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY']
`` INSERT INTO `mb00_root_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (490, '_pingme', '1') ``**WordPress database error:** [Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY']
`` INSERT INTO `mb00_root_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (490, '_encloseme', '1') ``

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cdsS.png) error in postmeta table

edit:- when i am running this query in phpmyadmin it ginver this error

SQL query:

INSERT INTO `mb00_root_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (490, '_pingme', '1')

MySQL said:

#1364 - Field 'meta_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: It looks like the meta_id does not have auto increment. So when you are trying to save the post, it tries to add a new row to the mb00_root_postmeta. But there is already an meta_id with the ID of 0.
So what I would do first is to see what plugin that is adding that table, then disable that plugin to see if that solves the problem.
If it is something yo uhave built your self then you need to set so the meta_id auto increse the ID

Comment: I have deactivated all the plugin but the issue is still coming